# Elegant grouping of pivoted CSV data in F#

Tags: f#

Suppose I have CSV rows like this:

```
email, item_code
alice@example.org, apple
, banana
, cherry
bob@example.org, apple
charlie@example.org, banana
, cherry
```

The emails should be "filled downwards" to complete the CSV. So this data tells us:

- `alice@example.org` bought `apple`, `banana` and `cherry`
- `bob@example.org` bought just `apple`
- `charlie@example.org` bought `banana` and `cherry`

And in F#, this data might be parsed to a list of lists:

```ml
let rows = 
  [
    [ "alice@example.org";   "apple"  ]
    [ "";                    "banana" ]
    [ "";                    "cherry" ]
    [ "bob@example.org";     "apple"  ]
    [ "charlie@example.org"; "banana" ]
    [ "";                    "cherry" ]
  ]
```

What is a good way to turn this lists of lists into a `Map` like so?

```ml
let purchases = 
  Map.empty
  |> Map.add "alice@example.org"   [ "apple"; "banana"; "cherry" ]
  |> Map.add "bob@example.org"     [ "apple" ]
  |> Map.add "charlie@example.org" [ "banana"; "cherry" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come up with is something like:

```
let (|EmptyString|NonEmptyString|) str =
    if System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)
    then EmptyString
    else NonEmptyString

let folder entries row =
    match row, entries with
    | [NonEmptyString as key; value], lastEntries ->
        (key, [value])::lastEntries
    | [EmptyString; value], (lastKey, lastValues)::tail ->
        (lastKey, value::lastValues)::tail
    | _ -> failwith "Invalid input"

rows
|> List.fold folder []
|> List.map (fun (key, values) -> key, List.rev values)
|> Map.ofList
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive solution:

```ml
let rec fill emailPrev = function
    | (email :: rest) :: tail ->
        let emailFill =
            if email = "" then emailPrev
            else email
        (emailFill :: rest) :: (fill emailFill tail)
    | [] -> []
    | _ -> failwith "Unexpected"

rows
    |> fill ""
    |> List.groupBy List.head
    |> List.map (fun (email, group) ->
        email, group |> List.collect List.tail)
    |> Map
    |> printfn "%A"
```

FWIW, I would also consider representing each CSV row as a tuple of `email * fruit`, rather than as a list.